# CSS: Force a div to fit to browser screen?

Tags: css, sharepoint, html

Okay, I'm trying to make a div fit to the size of the browser window. SO I have a div with height:100%. This is all well and good. However, this contains a table (in an ASPX control I can't change the code of, etc., etc.), and many levels down  there's a div with "height:1869px" (and overflow:auto and position:relative if that matters). This causes the table to be resized to fit that, and the whole page ends up scrolling. IE8 developer tools report my outer div only has a height of 896, but the table (the only child element of it) contained directly within has height 1888.

Here's the basic idea:

```
<div style="height:100%">
    <table><tr><td>
        <!-- A whole bunch of other stuff the WebPart spits out, including another couple divs -->
            <div style="height:1869px">
     </table></tr></td>
</div>
```

(While there are a lot of styles from classes, both my `height:100%` and its `height:1869px` are defined inline -- and mine must be because otherwise sharepoint puts `height:400px`)

I can't change anything below the outer div (it's generated by a SharePoint web part), and while it's possible to fix with a JavaScript hack (find the exact element with the problem and kill that), that's not a maintainable solution since the web part may change. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide some example markup to help explain? Also, which of these CSS properties come from CSS rules and which ones come from the style attribute?

Comment: Curious: Have you only tested on IE8?

Comment: That's not even proper html.. close td, then tr, then table, not backwards :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you gotta figure out what you want as your solution... if you want to restrict the inner objects to be shorter then you can use `max-height` and add `!important` so that it'll override the 1869px value

Comment: I don't think using !important is ever a good idea; depending on where the different CSS properties are coming from, I'm going to be very tempted to voted this down.

Comment: @LeguRi - !important is part of CSS for a reason, throwing it out because it tends to be kludgey is short sighted. You should use !important when you need to use it just like any other tool. Sometimes you don't have control over everything so you do what you have to do to make it go.

Comment: @mu is too short - CSS specificity is also part of CSS for a reason, and a better one than !important :P but given that all the rules the OP refers to are in style attributes !important might in fact be necessary - CSS specificty won't cut it.

Comment: Yup; that looks like the best option in this case. It might not be great design, but I'm just trying to workaround a couple SharePoint bugs, and this works perfectly here.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't putting `overflow: hidden` on the `<div />` work?

Comment: That just hides the bottom of the page (which is actually the most important part since I need the second cell of the table -- which contains navigation links) to be visible.

Comment: So uh... if you want everything to fit on one screen, something's going to have to get cut off. I take it you want the table to get cut off? That wasn't at all clear in your original question, but if so, then give it a max-height value as Mikhail suggests...